# iptables - how to change destination IP and port of packets mirrored to a NIC

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm struggling to find an answer and have tried many things but not getting anywhere.

I'm mirroring packets going to various IPs/ports to an interface on a linux box (I can see the packets arriving at this interface). I need to modify the destination IP and port to readdress these packets so that a monitoring tool can see them (which is listening on that destination IP/port). The packets do not need to be sent out from the machine or have traffic coming back, just readddressed. **These packets are obviously not starting a session or destined for the machine they are being mirrored to**. How can I do this with iptables (or any standard linux packages)?

Port forwarding does not work as the packets are not destined for the machine that they are arriving at. i.e. the following does not work: [Mirror all traffic from one port to another on localhost using iptables](https://superuser.com/questions/1289166/mirror-all-traffic-from-one-port-to-another-on-localhost-using-iptables)

To give more specifics, the linux box has two interface ens160 and ens192. ens192 has IP address 10.10.10.10, ens160 is irrelevant to the question here. Packets are being mirrored to ens192 (to the interface and NOT TO 10.10.10.10 - I can use tcpdump and see the packets getting to the interface). These packets could have any destination IP of anything other than 10.10.10.10, and to any port i.e. 1-65535. Any rerouting I've seen is done on packets arriving on IP 10.10.10.10 so no rules get applied and I do not see any rule increasing its packet count when using "iptables -t  -L -n -v".